# More than one scheduled local notification

Tags: ios7, notifications, uilocalnotification

I'm trying to make an app were you get 1 local notification every day of a total 64. All the notifications must be different. I have written two notifications so far and set their firedate to a specific date. But when I run the app the first notification comes aswell as the other one which should come a day later. How can I fix this please?!

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can     occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL     ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
// If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

NSCalendar *gregCalender = [[NSCalendar     alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent = [gregCalender components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateComponent setYear:2013];
[dateComponent setMonth:12];
[dateComponent setHour:20];
[dateComponent setMinute:19];

UIDatePicker *dd = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd setDate:[gregCalender dateFromComponents:dateComponent]];

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification setAlertBody:@"hejsan hoppsan"];
[notification setFireDate:dd.date];
[notification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[notification setSoundName:@"jingle-bells-sms.mp3"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
NSCalendar *gregorianCalender = [[NSCalendar alloc]initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

NSDateComponents *dateComponent2 = [gregorianCalender components:NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

[dateComponent2 setYear:2013];
[dateComponent2 setMonth:12];
[dateComponent2 setHour:20];
[dateComponent2 setMinute:20];

UIDatePicker *dd2 = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[dd2 setDate:[gregorianCalender dateFromComponents:dateComponent2]];

UILocalNotification *notification2 = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
[notification2 setAlertBody:@"tjena bena"];
[notification2 setFireDate:dd2.date];
[notification2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[notification2 setSoundName:@"jingle-bells-sms.mp3"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification2];



}
```

Comment: What does "1 local notification every of a total 64" mean?

Comment: i'm so sorry i meant "1 local notification every day of a total 64"

Comment: Can you set the exact time zone instead of default time zone?